# How do I ask a person to use something?

Tags: translation

I am playing a game with a mix of English players and Japanese players. It has a helpful translate feature built in but not everything is in there. For instance being able to tell a player to use an item.

As an example the item is "魔土器:解呪" I want to be able to politely say , "Please use Pomander Of Purity" but in Japanese (items often have different names in different language).

So in the case of my example would I say something like, "つかいます 魔土器:解呪"?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to politely say, "Please use Pomander Of Purity"

I think the most natural and common way of saying it would be...

> [魔土器]{まどき}の「[解呪]{かいじゅ}」**を[使]{つか}ってください**。

---

Breakdown:
を -- case particle as an object marker
使って -- te-form of verb 使う ("use")
ください -- honorific imperative form of subsidiary verb くれる ("do ~~ for me")

You use 「て-form + ください」("Please do ~~") for politely asking/requesting someone to do something.

Comment: 「魔土器」の読み方って「まどき」であってるんですかね・・

Answer (score 0):

The basic premise is that your sentence ordering is wrong.

In japanese all sentences/clauses must end with a verb. So you're suppose to say :

> name of items + を/は + verb(使います/用います)

But since you are using the command form. You can't use the normal dictionary form or the polite form, because it would mean the future tense.

> name of itemsを使います

Means "I/you will use the item".

You would use つかってください(please use) or just つかって(without please) for more direct and less polite commands.
So you would say :

> name of items + は/を + つかって / つかってください / つかってくれ

It is advisable to use the kanji 使う so identifying the meaning can be done quicker. You can also omit the は/を since it is clear from the context.

You can however split the sentence into 2. If the word "use" pops out in your mind first.

> つかって。"name of items".

Use it! The "name of items".